# How the destructor is called for heap object without delete operator?

Tags: c++, exception, new-operator

Can somebody explain here how destructor is called for object created in heap via new operator when the corresponding delete is not called.
In addition since in below code we are catching object via const reference and in destructor we are changing object value (i.e. setting n=0), so how is that possible.

```
class A
{
    private:
        int n;
    public:
        A()
        {
            n=100;
            std::cout<<"In constructor..."<<std::endl;
        }
        ~A()
        {
            n=0;
            std::cout<<"In destructor..."<<std::endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
  try
  {
      throw *(new A());
  }
  catch(const A& obj)
  {
      std::cout<<"Caught...."<<std::endl;
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Output from program (running on http://cpp.sh/3jm4x):

```
In constructor...
Caught....
In destructor...
```

Comment: And you know that the destructor is called because...? Have you tried running in a debugger, setting a breakpoint in the destructor to see where it's called from?

Comment: apologies here is the link : http://cpp.sh/3jm4x

Comment: Even though it might be elided, I suggest you add a copy-constructor as well. It might help you understand a little more. Or use some `static` counter that you increase in the constructor and check in the destructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`throw` makes a copy of the object, which is then destroyed automatically after `catch`. It is this destruction that you observe. The original heap-allocated object is indeed never destroyed.

Comment: When we are catching by const reference then why it is required to make a copy of object ?

Comment: @Kapil You don't *throw* a reference, you throw a *value*.

Comment: Is there any way to throw a reference in this case ?

Comment: Yes, [you can throw and catch just about anything](https://ideone.com/7EIADv) but there isn't much point. The linked example just picks up extra work and may completely <expletive deleted> up if `new` fails and throws.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have a memory leak, because the destructor that is called is not for the object allocated by `new`.

`throw *(new A());` results in a copy of the object and you can see that the copy constructor is called. And this is the object that the destructor is called for at the end of the scope for `catch`.

You can check the live demo [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96bc0a545296ce31).